# Toggle radio buttons between to different sets

Tags: button, radio-button, toggle

I would like to toggle selection between two different sets of radio buttons.
The condition that must be met is that if the user checks the button on one set (called in the example l1), it is unchecked in the other set (called in the example m1).

In other questions, it seems that it is only feasible solution is using Java scripts.

Below is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">Least</td>
        <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">Most</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{question1}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="l1" type="radio" value="-1" /></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="m1" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{question2}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="l1" type="radio" value="-2" /></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="m1" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{question3}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="l1" type="radio" value="-3" /></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="m1" type="radio" value="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{question4}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="l1" type="radio" value="-4" /></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><input name="m1" type="radio" value="4" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```